# Cmake Error Compiling Hydrogen 0.9.7 Beta1

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am attempting to compile Hydrogen 0.9.7 beta 2 with Cmake and I keep getting a cmakelists.txt error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:139 (MANDATORY_PKG):
                      Unknown CMake command "MANDATORY_PKG"

Reviewing the list of Cmake commands  I cant find a command that corresponds to MANDATORY_PKG. Is this deprecated language?

Here is the output of the attempted build.

```
tinman13@tinman13-scythion:~/hydrogen-1.0.0-beta1/build$ sudo cmake /home/tinman13  /hydrogen-1.0.0-beta1/build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:138 (INCLUDE):
  INCLUDE could not find load file:

    StatusSupportOptions


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:139 (MANDATORY_PKG):
  Unknown CMake command "MANDATORY_PKG".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tinman13/hydrogen-1.0.0-beta1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

CMakeOutput.log is a large rambling file but i'll post it if you like.

Is there anything that can be done to rectify this? Can i switch to an older version of CMake? Googling produces very little on the topic of unknown CMake commands and nothing related to Hydrogen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know CMake well, but I'd guess it's a macro [defined here in StatusSupportOptions](https://github.com/hydrogen-music/hydrogen/blob/0.9.7/cmake/StatusSupportOptions.cmake#L7)? The one it's failing to include, which was the first error you got. Can you solve that first?

Comment: Your CMake command is wrong. Either use `cmake ..` from your build directory or `cmake -S . -B ~/hydrogen-1.0.0-beta1/build` from your source directory.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. I attempted both solutions above and received this as output:                                                               CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:139 (MANDATORY_PKG):
  Unknown CMake command "MANDATORY_PKG".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tinman13/hydrogen-1.0.0-beta1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMake Error: Unable to open check cache file for write. /home/tinman13/hydrogen-1.0.0-beta1/build/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache

Comment: Did you emptied the build directory before rerunning CMake?

Comment: Yes I certainly did. I went back and reconfigured my repos and got an apt install that functions normal this time. Last apt install Hydrogen had no mixer panel, so I went to source to see if that would work. Id consider that matter done another way, no more need to compile cmake. Thanks for your input.